# Use of global variable in when part of drools rule

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

I have declared global variable in rule file which is type 'Employee'. I have to write a rule in which I can compare some field of global employee object with fields of 'Person' object. How can I do that ? Following rule I have tried which doesn't work :

```
global Employee emp;

rule "abc"
when 
$person : Person(joinDate == null , emp.joinDate != null , notify == false)
then 
$person.setNotify(Person.NOTIFY);
update($person);
end

rule "cde"
when 
$person : Person(joinDate != null , ! joinDate.equals(emp.joinDate) , notify == false)
then
$person.setNotify(Person.NOTIFY);
update($person);
end
```

How can I compare property of one bean with property of another bean which I am injecting as global variable ?

Comment: Please provide full code for reproducing the problem: how you create the session, define the global, what you insert... And please post correct code - global emp has no mode, which cannot be.

Comment: 'emp' is of Employee type. I just wanted know if Global variable's field can be compared with another Bean's field which I have specified in question ?

Comment: If you can compile it, it should work - but see my answer. As it is, I can't tell you more from what I see.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you change the value of the global `emp` and expect the rule to fire, which is a no-no.

Globals can be used in conditions, but they are assumed to remain stable since the Rule Engine has no way of knowing that the global has been changed.

If you want your rules to react to changing data, insert facts. That's why we have them.